# How to exclude or remove certain modes from major mode?

Tags: web-mode

I tried to use `column-enforce-mode` but I don't want it on `web-mode` I tried to disable it but without success.

```
(global-column-enforce-mode t)
(remove-hook 'web-mode 'column-enforce-mode nil)
```

The code above doesn't work. What is the proper way on doing it?

Comment: @Drew it is a minor mode to check code width, here is the repo https://github.com/jordonbiondo/column-enforce-mode

Comment: sorry, I cant understand what you mean on "recipe"? I am still learning about emacs and I am not that fluent in emacs lisp. btw what I want is to enable ```column-enforce-mode``` but not in ```web-mode``` especially on html files. Then I tried that code above but the column-enforce-mode is still active on html , I thought the ```remove-hook``` will disable it if I am on web-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc of `define-globalized-minor-mode` says:

> When a major mode is initialized, MODE is actually turned on just
>   after running the major mode’s hook.  However, MODE is not turned
>   on if the hook has explicitly disabled it.

That means you should explicitly disable `column-enforce-mode` in `web-mode-hook`. I.e.:

```el
(defun my-web-mode-hook-fun ()
  "Disable `column-enforce-mode' in `web-mode'."
  (column-enforce-mode -1))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'my-web-mode-hook-fun)
```

This is the general approach for globalized minor modes. It is not tested for your special case of `column-enforce-mode` since I don't use it. Please test the code and report whether it works.